# Scrolling to a target after a div is hidden

Tags: javascript

I have a page of divs that display thumbnail images. Each is set so that when it's clicked on, a larger version appears in a larger pair of divs, centered in the window. One is a frame, the inner div is the image. Those divs are initially hidden and become visible via a javascript:

```
document.getElementById('frame').style.visibility="visible". 
document.getElementById('print').style.visibility="visible".
```

They're sized and centered just right by the javascript but in the background it scrolls to the top of the page of thumbnails, so when closed, the user has to scroll down the page again to get back to where they were.

I've tried inserting the two divs in every conceivable place of the page, inside and outside the main page divs, top and bottom of the page...  I've also tried relative, absolute and even sticky positioning without luck.

So I pursued scrolling the page when the divs are closed (hidden again) but that too is failing whether I use anchors or scrolling. In the script below, if the the alert is active, it shows the page scrolled to the correct position in the background. As soon as the alert is closed, it jumps back to the top of the page. 'pid' is the id of the targeted thumbnail.

```
function hideprint() {
    document.getElementById('print').style.visibility="hidden"; 
    document.getElementById('frame').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById(pid).scrollIntoView();
    // alert(pid);
}
```

I've also tried 'display' instead of 'visibility' with the same results.

How can I display these divs then get the page to stay or return to where it's been scrolled to when they're closed?

Comment: Why does it scroll to the top in the first place? Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: Perhaps you have a button or link as close button. Try making that type=button in case it is submitting the page